# datetime parsing without changing timezone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, google-calendar-api, simpledateformat

I have date and time values in string type here.

- appDate = 2/19/2019
- startTime = 4:15 PM

I want to insert an event into the google calendar via api.

When I parse the date string it converts according to my local regional settings. I live in GMT+03.00 time zone. But I want to insert date and time as is in the string.

As is output:
{dateTime=2019-01-19T04:15:00.000+03:00, timeZone=America/New_York}

I need to get this:
{dateTime=2019-01-19T04:15:00.000-05:00, timeZone=America/New_York}

With this code block below, it inserts 8:15 pm into the google calendar.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm a", Locale.US);

String dateInString = appDate + " " + startTime;
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(date);

EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(startDateTime).setTimeZone("America/New_York");
```

Comment: In which time zone is your input date/time? (regardless of where it is parsed or where it will be stored)

Comment: My input values in GMT-05:00 time zone. I dont want to change anything in my input. Only parse string values into the Date format as is. And then send it to the Google Calendar.

Comment: I did not try Calendar object. Google Calendar api wants DateTime input type.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` allows you to specify the `TimeZone` to parse from.

eg:
`formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));`

Or if you just wanted a custom GMT-5 time zone (ie: without any location specific DST rules):
`formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5"));`

**Edit**: having had a chance to look at the second part of your problem, and take a look at the calendar api you are using - and assuming the google api classes you are using here are those in the `com.google.apis` groupId, `google-api-services-calendar` artifactId, then you want to also specify the `TimeZone` of offset when instantiating the `com.google.api.client.util.DateTime` instance.

Using the `SimpleDateFormat` with the specified timezone for New York to parse the string "2/19/2019 4:15 PM" into a date will get you a `java.util.Date` that wraps the long value 1550610900000 (regardless of your actual local timezone).Note that if you print the `toString()` of that `Date` it will give a date in your local machine's timezone. eg: for me its says "Wed Feb 20 05:15:00 SGT 2019".

The `DateTime` extracts that long value from the specified Date via getTime() and stores it as a long internally.

`DateTime` (or at least the version of the DateTime class I quickly grabbed to experiment with (*v3-rev364-1.25.0*) ) also has a constructor that takes a `TimeZone` whence it extracts an offset from UTC via `getOffset()`. If you don't pass it one it will use `TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(value)` internally. Later when its toString() is invoked it will render it using the offset it stored (which it got from the timezone).

Example:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.US);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
Date date = formatter.parse("2/19/2019 4:15 PM");

DateTime startDateTimeNY = new DateTime(date,TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")); 
DateTime startDateTimeSG = new DateTime(date,TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));   
DateTime startDateTimeNBO = new DateTime(date,TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Nairobi"));  
System.out.println(startDateTimeNY); //prints 2019-02-19T16:15:00.000-05:00
System.out.println(startDateTimeSG); //prints 2019-02-20T05:15:00.000+08:00
System.out.println(startDateTimeNBO); //prints 2019-02-20T00:15:00.000+03:00
```

(You can see the differing local times in the output there)

I haven't had time to confirm it, but looks like `EventDateTime` is just using the `toString()` from the `DateTime` for the dateTime value (if you don't have a `JsonFactory` set in it). (The TimeZone it stores it for another purpose?)

TLDR: Specifiying a `TimeZone` on the `SimpleDateFormat` lets you reads the date correctly from its source timezone, and to format the output as desired you also need to change your call to `DateTime` constructor to use the desired timezone thusly:

`DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(date,TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));`

Comment: I have tried this now. Output still wrong.  2019-01-19T12:15:00.000+03:00      After parse method it  automatically adds +03:00 . I want to prevent this.

Comment: @fdemir are you calling `setTimeZone` **before** calling `parse`?

Comment: Exactly. Before parsing.

Comment: why it adds +03:00 at the end of the date?

Comment: @fdemir - What do you mean by "it"? Are you printing the `Date` value to the console?

Comment: java.util.Date is just a wrapper around a timezone independent milliseconds after 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC values, so I'm guessing the other half of the problem lies in how the google calendar api classes being used here handle the timezones?

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. AM / PM is a problem now. Date and time is correct now. When I insert into the Google Calendar, it shows 4:15 AM not 4:15 PM. Thank you very much !

Comment: Oops! Sorry, didn't spot that one. The parsing format needs to use **hh** instead of **HH** for 12 hour times instead of 24. I better edit my answer...

Comment: It worked !!. You are definitely great guy. Excellent solution.

Comment: New problem occured :(  When the input string is "6/6/2019 2:15 PM"      startDateTimeNY value is will be  "2019-01-06T14:15:00.000-05:00"      time is correct bu date is wrong.

Comment: Another error in the format. Should be **MM** instead of **mm**. (And in answer to your *next* question, it shows -04:00 and not -05:00 because NY will go into daylight savings from 10 March to 3 November)

Comment: Thank you @Andrew.

Answer (score 4):

## java.time

You are encountering *very* common sources of confusion surrounding the legacy `java.util.Date` and related classes. You should use the newer `java.time` classes introduced in Java 8:

```java
System.out.printf("INFO - System default timezone: %s%n", ZoneId.systemDefault().getId());
// INFO - System default timezone: Europe/Moscow

// test data
String appDate = "2/19/2019";
String startTime = "4:15 PM";
String targetTimezone = "America/New_York";

String dateInString = appDate + " " + startTime;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy h:mm a");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateInString, formatter);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of(targetTimezone));

System.out.println(zdt);  // 2019-02-19T16:15-05:00[America/New_York]
```

As you can see, the `ZonedDateTime` has been created with the correct local time (16:15 = 4:15 PM), the correct offset (-05:00), and the time zone explicitly specified (America/New_York).

If you're lucky, the Google Calendar API will be able to work with the `java.time` classes. However, if you need to revert to a `java.util.Date` for whatever reason you can always convert by calling the new methods added to the old classes. Extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) from the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) (to adjust from zone to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)), then pass to the new [`Date.from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) method.

```java
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( zdt.toInstant() );

System.out.println(date);  // Wed Feb 20 00:15:00 MSK 2019
System.out.println(date.getTime());  // 1550610900000
```

Notice that the `java.util.Date` is printed using the current default time zone of the JVM, `Europe/Moscow`, so the date and time have been adjusted accordingly. However, both values (`2019-02-19T16:15-05:00[America/New_York]` and `Wed Feb 20 00:15:00 MSK 2019`) represent the same instant in time: 1550610900000 milliseconds after the epoch (`1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`).

Comment: How can I convert ZonedDateTime  to DateTime object? Thanks.